# Cannot delete user - entry missing in /etc/passwd - (networked user)

Tags: 16.04, user-management

I ran

```
sudo userdel <username>
```

but I received the following error

```
userdel: cannot remove entry '<username>' from /etc/passwd
```

I check the /etc/passwd file and I indeed cannot find an entry for the username - I CTRL+F'd through to check.

Help would be really appreciated, already used to the search bar and no satisfactory answers turned up.

Cheers!

EDIT:

I believe I know what may be the issue. The user I am trying to delete does not authenticate locally, but on a network as the login is the same as my university login details which is why it is not locally storing details in /etc/passwd - The question is now how can I delete this sort of user that is authenticating over a network - Could someone help me with that?

EDIT2: Upon request below is the contents of /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
sudoers:        sss
```

Comment: You've replaced the username with "<username>"? If you're doing that for privacy reasons please give a similar example of the username.

Comment: say i created a user called user1 -  

**sudo userdel user1**   -

and I received in return  

"**userdel: cannot remove entry user1 from /etc/passwd**"

Comment: Can you repeat that behavior? like if you useradd user2 then userdel user2?

Comment: Yep, I can confirm it works fine if I add a new user I can then delete the new user fine.

It might be worth stating that this computer already came with a user (university provided), I created a new user and am now trying to remove the old user. I have full root and admin privileges on both accounts

Comment: Have you tried using the `userdel` command with the `-r` switch?  Also, have you tried using `deluser` to remove the user account?

Comment: that doesn't work either but I believe I know what may be the issue.

The user I am trying to delete does not authenticate locally, but on a network as the login is the same as my university login details which is why it is not locally storing details in /etc/passwd  - The question is now how can I delete this sort of user that is authenticating over a network. I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful? [Locally deny login to users authenticated via LDAP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186542/locally-deny-login-to-users-authenticated-via-ldap)

Comment: Add the output of /etc/nsswitch.conf to your answer. sss and or winbind indicates active directory while ldap indicates older versions of active directory or something like openldap.

Comment: Apologies, I am not the greatest with linux as I didn't quite understand the latter part of your sentence, but I have edited my answer with the contents of /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: Read `man nsswitch` - your system is accepting user identification/authentication from the University server. You can't delete that user. The manager of the University's server can.

Comment: Oh, I don't want to delete the user on the remote server, I understand only the unversity can do that, I just don't want the user present on my local machine. As in there shouldn't be an option to log in with it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue.
I stopped the following services

```
systemctl stop ntpd smb winbind
```

created user:

```
useradd linuxuser
```

started the services

```
systemctl start ntpd smb winbind
```